# Kotlin Coroutines dependency going into Overload Resolution Ambiguity

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm having a production ready Kotlin code and I want to refactor it from changing all CompletableFuture requests to Coroutines, but when I add the `compile('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.0')` dependecy tu build.gradle, all my kotlin.collections imports are going into "Overload resolution ambiguity". Does anybody knows how to deal with this problem?

Here is a snippet from my code:

[image]

TX!

Comment: Be more specific. Show us a specific example where it happens.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, i've added a snippet.

Comment: Looks like some sort of bug, all four lines talk about the same function.

Comment: Yes, I also think that it's a bug...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I've removed the coroutines dependency from my build.gradle file. It seems that it was a problem with kotlin version, coroutines version and spring-kotlin plugin. I will try to upgrade my project to the latest Spring Boot version that contains the Kotlin coroutines by default.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this happens when indexes get stale in IDEA. Try to build with `gradle` to ensure there is no real clashes. Running `File` -> `Invalidate caches / Restart` should help.